# Using the UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uilabel, uistackview

I currently have a `UIStackView` inside of a `UIScrollView`, positioned in my storyboard. I then programmatically add multiple `UILabel` based on user input. When the program is run, instead of being able to scroll, all the labels cram within the defined view. When the first label is created it appears in the centre of the `UIScrollView`, and subsequent labels decrease spacing between each other and "try" to be centred. This eventually causes the view to become overloaded. Any ideas on why it isn't scrolling? Thanks.

[image: Image of List of Constraints]

Comment: Can you show us an image of the constraints in your stack view?

Comment: I added a link to in image of the list of constraints at the end of the original post.